# If condition in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to suppress a section by checking below requirement.

```
If scanmode and status=null (these fileds coming from database) then i need to suppress the section. If it is not null then i need check next condition if status in [c,d] .if it is false i need to suppress the section without checking next conditions.If it is true then i need to check next condition
```

{Status.status} >= 3 if it is >=3 then i need to check next condition {?Stack} <> "S" .

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly easy to accomplish. In the Section expert you create a custom formula under the "suppress" option that would look something like this:

```
if (scanmode = 0 and status = 0) else if (c = value and d = value) else.....
```

If you want multiple conditions to suppress the sections then you can use OR instead of AND.
I suggest you try to suppress with one condition first to see if the suppression works and then add on to that.

Hope that helps,

Chris